# How to set Time Range in UIDatePickerModeTime

Tags: ios, ios-4.2, ios4

Hello friends I am trying to set the Time Range Of the DatePicker in UIDatePickerModeTime,as we have MaxDate and MinDate,whether its possible to set Mintime and Maxtime selected by user,,

Suppose I want the user to select the time between 16:00 to 19:00 only for each day then how can I do it,,

Thanks&Regards
Ranjit

Hello friends I tried the below code
to set the start time range and its working fine...

```
NSDate *todaysDate =[NSDate date];

NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit |NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:todaysDate];


[comps setHour:16];
[comps setMinute:00];
[comps setSecond:00];

 NSDate *startDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];

 NSDateComponents *startcomps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[startcomps setDay:startDay-weekday];


 self.minDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:startcomps toDate:startDate   options:0];
```

but when I apply the same code to set the end time range its not working....can any body please help me out in this matter

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: Below ans is only for same date. But if dates are different like For today set time 3.00 to 23.00 and tomorrow will be 12.00 to 23.00

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved your problem (using IB, but I think you could do that programmatically too).

**Using IB:**

1. Select your `Date picker`.
2. Open `Utilities -> Attribute inspector`
3. In block `Constraints` :
4. Select `Minimum Date` and set its value `01/01/1970 16:00:00`
5. Select `Maximum Date` and set its value `01/01/1970 19:00:00`
6. Set value `Date` to `01/01/1970 16:00:00`

Comment: hey Nekto how can we do it programatically

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html